# TypeError: random() takes no arguments (2 given)

Tags: python, tkinter

Когда выберем диапазон то программа должна сгенерировать случайное десятичное число в выбраном диапазоне, но выдаёт ошибку.

```
from tkinter import*
root=Tk()
from random import*

def ssg():
   if but['text'] == 'Сгенерировать случайное число' and i.get()==2:
       lab['text']=random(0,1)
   elif but['text'] == 'Сгенерировать случайное число' and i.get()==3:
       lab['text']=random(1,100)

i=DoubleVar()


r4=Radiobutton(root,text='от 0 до 1',variable=i,value=2)
r4.grid(row=5,column=0, sticky='w')

r5=Radiobutton(root,text='от 1 до 100',variable=i,value=3)
r5.grid(row=5,column=3, sticky='w')



but=Button(root,text='Сгенерировать случайное число',command=ssg)
but.grid(row=3,column=0,columnspan=3)

lab=Label(root,text='')
lab.grid(row=4,column=0,columnspan=3)
```

Comment: Такую ошибку выдает потому что вы пытаетесь задать несколько аргументов в функцию `random.random` которая в принципе вообще не принимает никаких переменных, а выводит рандомное число от 0 до 1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Тут нужно смотреть документацию библиотеки random для python, вот вариант [на русском](https://pythonworld.ru/moduli/modul-random.html)

Если нужно **любое число** в диапазоне от А до B, вместо `random(A, B)` используйте `random.uniform(A, B)` или `uniform(A, B)` в вашем случае

Если нужно **целое число** `random.randint(A, B)`

Comment: Спасибо, вы очень помогли

Answer (score 1):

Потому, что  функция **random()** генерирует случайное число в диапазоне от 0.0 до 1.0. Используйте функцию **randint()**:

```
import random
number_one = random.randint(20, 35)
print(number_one) #27

number_two = random.random()
print(number_two) #0.32161791480941126
```

Comment: Спасибо. Мне надо было от 0,0 до 1,0,

Comment: @A.Kross хм, а зачем же вы тогда пытались передать в аргументы функции целые числа? :)

Comment: я думал что так я поставлю диапазон, я  не знал что random работает без аргументов